# socketio client is receiving "double + 1" events

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

Im playing around with socketio and I have a bug that others seem to be getting but I haven't found a valid solution.

This is my server code:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('New client has connected')

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected')
    })    

    socket.on('clicked', () => {
        console.log('recieved a click')
        socket.broadcast.emit('clicked')
    })
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log('server is up and running on PORT:', port))
```

And this is my client code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

const client = socketIOClient('http://localhost:4001')

function App() {

  const [timesClicked, setTimesClicked] = useState(0)

  client.on('clicked', data => {
    console.log('received click')
    setTimesClicked(prevState => prevState + 1)
  })

  const handleClick = () => client.emit('clicked')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Times clicked: {timesClicked}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>INCREMENT</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click on the increment button, from my 2nd window, I see the console log: 'received click'

After 2 clicks, it becomes: `(3) Received click`

After 3 clicks, it becomes: `(7) Received click`

After 4 clicks, it becomes: `(15) Received click`

```
console.log('recieved click')
setTimesClicked(timesClicked + 1)
```

The `console.log` is being called multiple times but `setTImesClicked` seems to be correct. After 5 clicks, `timesClicked` is equal to 5 but I see `(31) Recieved click`

For some reason, it seems to be doubling the previous amount of events and adding 1 to it. Does anyone see what I did incorrectly here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a state changes in react the whole component is executed again. This means that all the code in your `App` function will run every time that the `timesClicked` state is changed and will cause your socket event listener to be attached over and over, and that creates the duplication of the values.

Use the `useEffect` hook with an empty array as second parameter. Attach the listener to the socket inside this hook. Using the empty array will tell React that this effect is not dependent on states or other values that are susceptible to change and should not run more than once.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

const client = socketIOClient('http://localhost:4001')

function App() {

  const [timesClicked, setTimesClicked] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = () => client.emit('clicked')

  useEffect(() => {
    client.on('clicked', data => {
      console.log('received click')
      setTimesClicked(timesClicked + 1)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Times clicked: {timesClicked}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>INCREMENT</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I was so sure I tried this... I think I mistakenly included `timesClicked` within the 2nd parameter of useEffect.

This worked!